# Sharepoint 2013 adding Image for ribbon control in the Ribbon bar

Tags: branding, image-display, file-icons

I am facing an strange issue when I develop a feature in SP 2013.
When I use icon picture which is a png file , size `32x32 pixels`

[image]

I got the following result :

[image]

But if I use a ico file I get the whole icon.

File:

[image]

Second Result:

[image]

Is there someone who can tell me, if this is only possible to use an ico file  in the SharePoint 2013 Ribbon or I am missing any step when I used the png image?

Comment: What is the Pixels per Inch (PPI/DPI) set on the image you have created? Make sure it is 72 PPI, not higher

Comment: The Pixels has been always 32x32 96 DPI.
 I tried to reduce the DPI with a third party software for the PNG format  but  I never went down under 96 DPI event though I set up 20x20 pixels.
Instead of when i convert the file to ICO or JPG and it works fine , I think this link can explain why (http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2010/02/the-myth-of-dpi/)